# How to override core vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/ar_SA.xml

Tags: magento2.3, overrides, magento2.3.1, magento-core, vendor

I want to override **`vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/ar_SA.xml`** because for my **Arabic store** currency symbol was not working.

By referring to this [URL](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13207) I got the solution.

But which is come under core changes. we should not change the core. So, I need to override this file. Did anyone have any idea?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Refer the link you have to helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384750/magento-2-how-to-customize-currency-symbol-and-format-based-on-locale/39410383